# In Phase 10, can Wild Cards be discarded?

Tags: phase-10

Can you discard a wild card in order to NOT have them as points in your hand?

For instance, I was about to go out and someone else discarded their wild so that they wouldn't have those extra 25 points.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean as your normal discard on your turn, yes.

From the [rules](http://www.tactic.net/site/rules/FIN/03140.pdf):

> End your turn by discarding any one of your cards onto the top of the discard pile.

For clarity, if you by "about to go out" you mean that it is your turn, then no, your opponent cannot discard anything when it is not their turn.